# Select Where And after $

Tags: php, mysql

Does anyone know how can I use AND in this case?

```
$selected="SELECT * FROM Table WHERE t2 = '".$value1."' AND t1 <> '".$value1."' AND t1<> '".$value3."'";
```

Thanks.

Comment: What problem are you having with your query?  Another option is to use `not in`...

Comment: after `'".$value1."'` AND is not working

Comment: Nothing looks wrong.  Try printing out your actual sql and then it may be more obvious.  Could you have single quotes in your values?  Maybe you should try using parameterized queries instead.

Comment: To be honest I don't know how to use that one.

Comment: This should help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php

Comment: Describe what happens with you current query. Maybe the second `$value1` should be `$value2`, we can only guess at this point. Also this is too minimal of a PHP version if this is a PHP issue...

Comment: `echo $selected;` paste that

Answer (score 0):

```
$selected="SELECT * FROM Table WHERE t2 = '".$value1."' AND t1 <> '".$value1."' AND t1 <> '".$value3."'";
```

just provide space.

Or you can use NOT IN

```
$selected="SELECT * FROM Table WHERE t2 = '".$value1."' AND t1 not in ('".$value1."','".$value3."')";
```

Comment: Still does not work. The problem is about `'".$value1."'`, so after this AND does not work. This is the only problem actually.

Comment: What is the data type of $value1?

Comment: all values are strings.

Comment: then possibly `$value1` could contain ' or " ? Please post the error and output.

Comment: Perhaps a sample of actual data and the $value string and the result you think you should get ....